# How to view details in the PRAGMA showcase?

Tags: context, examples

The [PRAGMA Web site](http://www.pragma-ade.com/) has a link to a [showcase](http://www.pragma-ade.com/showcase.pdf). However, when I open this PDF, it shows just 2 pages with a black menu. It must contain links to other documents, but it does not work. I have tried Evince and Adobe Acrobat. How can I view this showcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are on the page, click the words (articles, papers, notes, etc.)

Direct links to all 10 showcase PDF documents are here: [CONTEXT documentation suite - PDF](http://www.pragma-ade.com/document-2.htm).

On [CONTEXT documentation suite - HTML](http://www.pragma-ade.com/document-1.htm), more files are available, which are also linked in the PDFs. For example click on *a couple of articles* and on the right bottom of the web page you can see **next** and **previous** buttons for navigating. I mention that because I don't find this intuitive, a simple list for each topic would have been easier. There are 8 articles, but only one is listed on each web page.

Comment: I'm sure Village is aware of that. But when you click, nothing happens (at least not for me either).

Comment: @Psirus: Village did not say that he tried clicking the words, though he said what he saw. It works for me with the Adobe Reader X, Firefox plugin. If he would change his question telling that this word clicking doesn't work, with giving details of viewer versions, I gladly remove this advice.

Comment: Yes, I tried clicking on the links. As for the 10 PDFs you showed, are those all that is in the showcase or are those 10 PDFs links to still more documents?

Comment: @Village They contain links to further documents. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Stefan -- maybe there are **next** and **previous** buttons on some pages, but not on the "graphics" pages.  there, if you click on the graphic, it progresses to the next graphic in that "series" (this is mentioned on the first page after the intro); you have to click on the bottom margin to get to the next "series".  but it would have been easier with buttons; i don't find the indirect approach at all intuitive, and only experimented to find out the reason for the question.  i understand Village's confusion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I understand it too, as I assume those PDF documents may not work with all PDF readers, regarding their links. That's why I mentioned that document area where he can browse and download. Also, I don't find that previous/next browsing on the web page intuitive, that's why I explicitely described that.